# Aws Lambda does not invoke the child Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function to read data from an sql table, to manipulate the data and call another lambda function to email the results to several parties.

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var sql = require("mssql");
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({ region: "eu-central-1" });

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let dataQuery = sqlQuery(); /*prepare the query*/
   
    let result = {};
    try{
        result = await getData(dataQuery); /*fetch data*/
    }catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    const data = prepareRes(result.recordsets[0][0])
   
    const emails = processData(JSON.parse(data));
    const params ={
        FunctionName: "testSesSendEmail",
        InvocationType: "Event",
        Payload: '<h2>Some Sample</h2>',
        LogType        : 'None',
        };
        
    
    return emails.map(async email => {
        console.log(email.emailAddr) /* everything works fine */
        
       lambda.invoke(params, function(err,data){
           console.log('callback entered')
           if (err) {console.log(err, err.stack)}
           else {
               console.log('Lambda function 1 invoked!');
                console.log(data); 
           }
       })
       
    })
    
   
     
    
   
};
```

I have filled the payload with dummy data for testing purposes.
The child lambda seems not to be invoked. I have already set up the necessary Iam policies and roles, attached them to the parent function.
Can't figure out whats wrong.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your lambda running inside a VPC?

Comment: @jellycsc yes. I have put both functions in the same VPC but to no avail

Comment: Ok, did your lambda timeout when it tries to invoke the second lambda?

Comment: No it doesn't. But it doesnt log the console message in the lambda callback at all.

Comment: How about including the log output in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting `emails.map(...)` to return? It's going to be an array of undefined values, the same length as the `emails` array, because your inner callback function doesn't return a value. Instead of that, you need it to return an array of promises.

Also, the return value from an async Lambda handler should be a single promise, not an array of promises, so you need to collapse that array of promises to a single promise. The typical way to do this is with `Promise.all()` but be aware of [other options](https://dev.to/viclafouch/promise-allsettled-vs-promise-all-in-javascript-4mle).

Try something like this:

```
const promises = emails.map(email => lambda.invoke(params).promise());  
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Note that this code (and yours) does not actually use the `email` parameter in any meaningful way, so you'll need to fix that.

Also, change this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
```

to this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
```

Don't use (or even offer) callback in an async Lambda handler.

Also, note that you are invoking the child Lambdas asynchronously, because of `InvocationType='Event'`. That may be what you want, but just wanted to check.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, but I am now getting TypeError: Promise.All is not a function. The child function is still not invoked. The reason i did not use the email parameter in the logic was to simplify. Once I get invoke running i will put it in the logic.

Comment: The problem is that I have put the both lambdas in a vpc. Parent  needs to be in a vpc to be able to make the database query. But when I move both lambdas out of the vpc they work fine (except for the database query). How do I have to configure the vpc to work fine for both of them?

Comment: Typo, apologies. It’s `Promise.all(...)` but hopefully a quick search helped you resolve that already. The Lambda that invokes the other Lambda needs to have a network route to the AWS Lambda service endpoint. When running in VPC, that means either a) private subnet has default route to a NAT in a public subnet or b) You use VPC Endpoints to reach the Lambda service. The Lambda should run in a private subnet. This is a different issue to your coding problem. There is available documentation on how to do this with a quick search.